# iTerm2 - zsh - keep history of commands when opening a new pane

Tags: terminal, zsh, history, iterm2, zshrc

with `zsh` on `MacOS Catalina`, when I split my current window of `iTerm2` by opening a new pane, I would like to be able to keep in this new pane the history of commands of previous pane (which is still opened).

Here my current config into `~/.zshrc` :

```
# History
export HISTFILE="$HOME/.zsh_history"
HISTSIZE=10000000
export SAVEHIST=$HISTSIZE
# Avoid duplicates
#setopt HIST_IGNORE_ALL_DUPS
# Remove duplicates in history
function remove_duplicates() {
   echo "$(history 0 | sort -k2 -k1nr | \
   uniq -f1 | sort -n | cut -c8-)" > $HISTFILE
}
remove_duplicates();
setopt inc_append_history

# When the shell exits, append to the history file instead of overwriting it
shopt -s histappend
```

What is missing or what did I do wrong in this config ?

and Just a question : when I open a new pane, did `~/.zshrc` file is executed (I mean sourced like `source ~/.zshrc`) ?

Comment: `shopt` isn't a `zsh` command, though `setopt inc_append_history` should be the option you need. You should also use `HIST_IGNORE_ALL_DUPS` to prevent duplicate entries, rather than trying to filter the list yourself.

Comment: @chepner. ok thanks but why have I have to type the command `history` in the pane where I am to have access to the `shared history`. Indeed, **If I type history in one of two pane (assuming I have 2 panes in a window)**, **then after**, I can have access to the **commands history done on the other pane**. How to circumvent this issue and avoid to type systematically the command `history`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
 setopt share_history
```

According to `man zshoptions`:

> This option both imports new commands from the history file, and also causes your typed commands to be appended to  the  history file  (the  latter  is like specifying INC_APPEND_HISTORY, which should be turned off if this option is in effect).